# Device.StartTimer equivalent in xamarin native PCL

Tags: xamarin, timer, task, portable-class-library

I want to call a method after certain delay.

In Xamarin.Form [Device.StartTimer](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Device.StartTimer/) is available.

```
Device.StartTimer(2000,() =>{});
```

Likewise we can do easily in xamarin native

```
System.Threading.Timer timerO = new System.Threading.Timer(this.methodtobeinvoked,”timerO", 2000, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
```

But when it comes to PCL in Xamarin native we can't use both.
It seems like

`System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(2000)` is easiest option available in PCL but this one blocks main thread and I can create a thread and call he delay to take this off from main thread but I don't want to fall into the trap of using multithreading ... is there any simple solution available that will let us call a method after the time is elapsed.

Answer (score 0):

Execute ticktock every second...

```
        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000), loop1); // every 1 second
        bool loop1()
        {
            ticktock(); // execute every second
            return true;
        }
```

Leave out the return statement and you will execute ticktock once, after a one second delay.